# Find stream of events that are not grouped using coGroupFunction

Tags: apache-flink, correlation, flink-streaming

How can we find stream of events that are not matched with other events, when using `CoGroupFunction`?

Lets consider people are communicating over a phone call. In `Tuple2<String, Integer>`, `f0` is name of person and `f1` is phone number they are calling to OR receiving call from.
We have paired them using `coGroup`, however we are missing people who are getting calls from person outside the world.

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> callers = env.fromElements(
        new Tuple2<String, Integer>("alice->", 12), // alice dials 12
        new Tuple2<String, Integer>("bob->", 13),   // bob dials 13
        new Tuple2<String, Integer>("charlie->", 19))
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampExtractor(Time.seconds(5)));

DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> callees = env.fromElements(
        new Tuple2<String, Integer>("->carl", 12), // carl received call
        new Tuple2<String, Integer>("->ted", 13),
        new Tuple2<String, Integer>("->chris", 7))
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampExtractor(Time.seconds(5)));;

DataStream<Tuple1<String>> groupedStream = callers.coGroup(callees)
        .where(evt -> evt.f1).equalTo(evt -> evt.f1)
        .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
        .apply(new IntEqualCoGroupFunc());

groupedStream.print(); // prints 1> (alice->-->carl) \n 1> (bob->-->ted)

//DataStream<Tuple1<String>> notGroupedStream = ..; // people without pairs in last window
//notGroupedStream.print(); // should print charlie->-->someone \n someone->-->chris

env.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, the simplest solution seems to be changing the `IntEqualCoGroupFunc`, so that instead of `String` it returns `(Boolean, String)`.
This is because `coGroup` processes also those elements that do not have matching keys, those elements will have one `Iterable` empty in the function `coGroup(Iterable<IN1> first, Iterable<IN2> second, Collector<O> out)` i.e. for Your case it would receive `("->chris", 7)` as `first` and empty `Iterable` as `second`.

The change of the signature could allow You to easily emit also results that do not have matching keys and simply split them into the separate streams at later stage of processing.

```
// Implementation of IntEqualCoGroupFunc
@Override
public void coGroup(Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> outbound, Iterable<Tuple2<String, Integer>> inbound,
        Collector<Tuple1<String>> out) throws Exception {

    for (Tuple2<String, Integer> outboundObj : outbound) {
        for (Tuple2<String, Integer> inboundObj : inbound) {
            out.collect(Tuple1.of(outboundObj.f0 + "-" + inboundObj.f0)); //matching pair
            return;
        }
        out.collect(Tuple1.of(outboundObj.f0 + "->someone")); //inbound is empty
        return;
    }

    // outbound is empty
    for (Tuple2<String, Integer> inboundObj : inbound) {
        out.collect(Tuple1.of("someone->-" + inboundObj.f0));
        return;
    }
    //inbound also empty
    out.collect(Tuple1.of("someone->-->someone"));
}
```

Output as follows:

```
2> (someone->-->chris)
2> (charlie->->someone)
1> (alice->-->carl)
1> (bob->-->ted)
```